# refer to table in ggplot function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plotting pipeline as follows

```r
df %>% 
    count(sub_category, name="count") %>%
    arrange(desc(count)) %>%
    slice_head(n=10) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=reorder(sub_category, count), y=count)) +
        geom_bar(stat='identity', fill='steelblue') +
        geom_text(aes(label=count), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5)) +
        labs(title="Top 10 Sub-Categories", x="Product Sub-Category", caption=paste0('total items=', sum(count)))
```

As you can in above code, only the top 10 rows of df (grouped by sub-category) are supplied to `ggplot()` and in the `labs()` function I am trying to add a `caption` with total number of items (rows) included only in the top 10 rows. Is there a way to refer to table used by ggplot, something like in dplyr we can do `.$count` or `.data[['count']]`?

I know I can store the intermediate table and then pass it to ggplot2, but I am just curious if there is a way to do the above without storing the intermediate results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Try this one

```
mtcars %>% 
  {ggplot(data=., aes(disp, hp)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   labs(title="Top 10 Sub-Categories", 
        x="Product Sub-Category", 
        caption=paste0('total items=', sum(.$cyl)))}
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that the key part of your answer is initially hidden because it extends outside the limits of the viewport.  A little judicious formatting would be helpful.